# Can't find where to start making my newsletters

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, newsletter, ce-1.9.2.4, create

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4, can't find where to start making my newsletters

Comment: You want to build a custom newsletters?

Comment: goto admin>Newseller section

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to create a newsletter, to do so you need to go to **Newsletter > Newsletter Templates** in the backend and click the **Add new template** button.

Fill the form and click the preview button to preview the result.

When you're done you need to go back to Newsletter > Newsletter Templates, select the template you just created and click the **Queue Newsletter** in the mass action drop down.